# How to pass array in laravel where condition?

Tags: php, mysql, database, frameworks, laravel

```
    $table='user';
    $conditions=array(
      'uname' => 'test', 
      'pwd' => '123'); //uname and pwd are the column names

    DB::table($table)->where($conditions)->get();
```

while excuting above code its showing following error

```
ErrorException

strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Can any one help me pls.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which classes you are using but your php compilator said that you passed array instead of string, so maybe try pass conditions in string format:

```
$conditions = "uname='test'&pwd='123'";
```

**UPDATE**
As you can see in docs (http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects), you can only pass strings to `where` method so you have to do sth like that:

```
$select = DB::table($table);
foreach($conditions as $column=>$value){
    $select->where($column,'=',$value);
}
$result = $select->get();
```

Comment: I am using a query builder of laravel. I don't know why it's not accepting array inside the where condition. If we use string like that we need to use 'whereraw()' by using in this way its getting result but I want output by passing array elements inside. I hope we have something for that.